# how to clear memory and fix memory leak Java

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I reduced my problem to this case, it's getting garbage in memory even without having any references out of scope. I wanted to know how to solve it, in C I would clear the memory myself, but in java we have to trust GC (as far as I know). What to do when the GC doesn't do its job right?

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        try{
            Long l[] = new Long[10000000];
            l = null;
          }
          catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
          }
        
        System.gc();

        while(true){
              Long l[] = new Long[10000000];
        }
    }
```

*java.lang.OutOfMemoryError* **-Xmx64m**

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of Java's garbage collector is that you don't deal with allocating/deallocating memory. Running

```
System.gc();
```

Is just a suggestion to the JVM to run the garbage collector.

> What to do when the GC doesn't do its job right?

I think any seasoned Java developer can agree that if you get a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, it's because YOU did something wrong, not the garbage collector. Look at your code. You're allocating an array of 10 million longs at a time. A primitive long is 8 bytes. 8 * 10 million is 80 million bytes. Or about 80 megabytes. And this is giving you the benefit of the doubt, a Long object has even more overhead.

> -Xmx64m

Is 64 megabytes less than 80 megabytes? To answer your original question, the garbage collector did it's job right, it's job isn't to magically create more memory than the maximum allocated.

Comment: In fairness, he is only allocating an array, not filling it, so the JVM needs only create enough room to store 10 million pointers. And if the JVM uses compressed object pointers, that's just 40 MB. However, since the heap usually consists of several segments (generations, ...), a 64 MB heap will have segments to small to contain a 40MB array.

Comment: @meriton the segmentation is not an issue on up-to-date JVMs. The problem here is that there is an array allocation attempt while the previously allocated array is still in the heap.

Comment: @Holger: Good point, I totally missed that the new allocation happens while the old array is still reachable. This code therefore needs at least 80MB of heap memory.

Comment: @meriton indeed. When I run this with JDK 17 with `-Xmx80m`, it runs forever. It also runs with `-Xcomp -Xmx64m`, as the forced compilation eliminates dangling references to unused objects, but then, it starts significantly slower.

Comment: So you're saying that keeping an inaccessible variable in RAM is doing the job correctly? Any C programmer would see it as nonsense, laziness or carelessness to clean up the memory properly. The GC should clean the garbage and what is a completely inaccessible variable if not garbage? And this one about increasing capacity makes no sense. It's like, after the trash is full, you buy a new one instead of taking the trash out.

Comment: I don't need more memory than allocated, read correctly the code "l" is inaccessible, I don't need it anymore and I want to allocate something the exact size of it. The GC is not doing its job properly, if it was there would be no need to increase my memory, pretending not to see that half of it would be used to store useless garbage.

Comment: @meriton is not accessible.

Comment: @meriton oh yeah I certainly doubt allocating a single Long array of length 10 million caused the error. but the lesson here is if you write bad code designed to fail like this, don't be surprised when it does.

Comment: @Kws so use C then if you think it's nonsense. or better yet, write your own garbage collector since you think the provided one isn't doing its job properly. the whole reason people still use low level languages like C and C++ is because automatic garbage collection isn't perfect; it's a program running in your program that automatically manages memory for you.

Comment: @TheCornInspector it would be enough to have the option to collect the garbage manually in cases where it is noticeable that the GC is not doing the job perfectly

Comment: What you have here, is a rare corner case. The main method is executed exactly once, so it is never fully JIT compiled. Real life applications do not perform significant work in the main method. And the option to fix the issue manually, does exist. Just change the loop to `while(true){ Long[] l = new Long[10000000]; l = null; }`